# Strange MySQL foreign key error

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

For an unknown reason I cannot create MySQL foreign keys anymore.
Symptoms:

- This is happening on *all* databases and tables in my MySQL installation, with no prior change from me.
- When trying to tick the MySQL Workbench foreign table field box to add a foreign key the box is refusing to tick.
- Receiving an error `General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint` when trying to programatically add a foreign key.

My `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` output for foreign keys:

> ---
>
> ```
> LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
> ------------------------
> ```
>
> 2017-03-23 20:11:34 0x23c4 Error in foreign key constraint of table timu/#sql-17bc_1a:
>     foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete restrict:
>    Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
>    referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
>    in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
>    Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
>    tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
>    cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.

Things I have tried:

- Made sure the database, server and tables and columns all follow the same charset and collation
- Made sure everything is InnoDB
- Made sure the columns are of the exact same type
- Uninstalled all MySQL components except the MySQL installer and then reinstalled everything from scratch.

All this especially the fact the this is happening across *all* tables and databases on my local MySQL leads me to believe that it has to be something with the MySQL instance.

Comment: Well, the error says the referenced table has no index on the referenced column. Your list of things you checked doesn't include the check for that. Please add the result of `show create table users`. What happens if you create new tables: `create table fktest1 (id int primary key); create table fktest2 (id int primary key, constraint foreign key (id) references fktest1 (id));`. Does that work? If not, please provide the error message/status for these. How did you reinstall your database? Did you make a backup, or did you keep the data directory?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Solarflare. Honestly I'm not sure what I did right this morning. Basically I did the following (but cannot guarantee this was the solution): created a new database and ran my programmatic migrations, which worked! The problem is now **mostly** solved because I can add the foreign keys programmatically for *all* database. Even that statement of yours worked across two databases. The only problem left now is the visual MySQL Workbench problem that I cannot tick the tickbox for foreign key field.

Comment: Oh and there was/is an index on the foreign table/field!
I feel silly posting an answer because I honestly don't know what in my processes fixed it haha

Comment: Glad it got fixed, although we don't know how. The Workbench will only allow you to tick a field if you have at least one field in the referenced table that could be used (correct type AND an index on it). Since your error message complained about the missing index too, (re-)check that the workbench knows of that index too. Maybe refresh your model after whatever fixed your problem in your database to let the workbench know the indexes are back.